# Как прервать цикл внутри функции при перезапуске ее?

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы, for

Внутри функции цикл, как его прервать при перезапуске функции?

```
function test(reset){

    for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
        if(reset){ break; } 
    }
}

test();

let reset = document.querySelector('.reset');

reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
    test(1);
});
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152041/discussion-on-question-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Для примера, как остановить цикл внутри функции.

Пример с созданием функции, которая останавливает цикл. Этот подход предполагает передачу объекта и вызов остановки цикла выполнением созданной функции. Полезно тем, что не надо держать внешнюю глобальную переменную.

Так же, допустим при "многопоточности/многоклиентности"(допустим сервер обслуживает пользователей по сокету), для каждого подключения можно создать свои обработчики и управлять ими в рамках текущих сессий.

```js
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
  const start = document.getElementById('start');
  const stop = document.getElementById('stop');
  const parameter = {};

  function increment(params) {
    const iteration = setInterval(() => {
      counter.innerText = +counter.innerText + 1;
    }, 300);
    params.stop = function () {
      clearInterval(iteration);
      delete params.stop;
    }
  }

  increment(parameter);

  start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!parameter.stop) increment(parameter);
  });

  stop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (typeof parameter?.stop === 'function') {
      parameter.stop();
      counter.innerText = '0';
    }
  });
  
  // Пример параллельного запуска
  
  function many() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const param = {}
      const rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 2000);
      increment(param);
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (typeof param?.stop === 'function') {
          param.stop();
          console.log(`Остановлн поток ${i}`);
        }
      }, rand);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('many').addEventListener('click', many);
```

```html
<button id="start">Старт</button>
<button id="stop">Стоп</button>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<button id="many">Параллельно</button>
```

Ну а это классический цикл и способ его прервать через внешнюю переменную

```js
async function sleep() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 300);
    })
  }

  const counterLoop = document.getElementById('counterLoop');
  const startLoop = document.getElementById('startLoop');
  const stopLoop = document.getElementById('stopLoop');

  let isLoop = true;
  async function iterate() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 9999; i++) {
      if (!isLoop) break;
      await sleep();
      counterLoop.innerText = +counterLoop.innerText + 1;
    }
    counterLoop.innerText = '0';
  }

  startLoop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!isLoop) {
      isLoop = true;
      iterate();
    }
  })

  stopLoop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    isLoop = false;
  });
  
  iterate();
```

```html
<button id="startLoop">Старт</button>
<button id="stopLoop">Стоп</button>
<div id="counterLoop">0</div>
```

Comment: Немного сложновато для меня, но интересно. Попробую разобраться, спасибо )

Comment: @Вячеслав Тогда берите второй вариант. Если у вас нет запуска в параллельных процессах одной и той же функции, то вам как раз он подойдет

Comment: мне нужно избежать параллельного запуска ) При повторном запуске функции, прерывать цикл внутри этой функции, который был запущен при первом запуске функции ) Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: @Вячеслав, параллельный запуск вообще невозможен. Прочитай про event loop в js.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Если у вас нет запуска в параллельных процессах одной и той же функции".

Comment: @Вячеслав JS работает синхронно и если даже запустить 100 вызовов одной и той же функции, то выполняться они будут так или иначе последовательно. Можно воркерами разделить вычислительные ресурсы и запараллелить ряд действий, но основной процесс будет все равно работать последовательно и синхронно. В моей фразе под параллельностью стоит понимать как: множественный вызов одной функции из разных мест. Если для остановки использовать одну глобальную переменную, то первый завершенный вызов остановит все остальное

Comment: Да это уже совсем в другу степь ) Код в посте совсем простой, а тут про воркеры уже и параллели )) Мне нужно просто стопорить цикл внутри функции, когда перезапускаю эту функцию ) Сейчас у меня получается, что при первом запуске функции стартует цикл внутри нее, потом перезапускаю функцию, цикл от первого запуска продолжает работать... при этом в процесс подмешивается цикл из второго запуска )) в итоге выдает в консоль значения из первого и второго цикла вперемешку.. я думал они как-то параллельно работают )

Comment: Но, видимо, не параллельно все же, а по очереди.. итерация из 1 цикла, итерация из 2..

Comment: @Вячеслав, я русским языком сказал - невозможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy что невозможно?

Comment: @Вячеслав короче... я попытался подсказать, но не вышло))) напишу напрямую:   сделай свой цикл (в том самом вопросе) не через `while(!response.ok)`, а через ту самую рекурсию, что я показал в комментарии (только вместо таймаута будет await функций), т.е. делаешь `await` потом, проверяешь ответ и либо перезапускаешь функцию на переисполнение, либо возвращаешь значение.......работа с отменой - через внешний флаг

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, у меня там была рекурсия, посоветовали сделать через while, в предыдущей теме )) чтобы упростить, сделать более 'плоским' код ) Ладно, надо еще подумать, будет чем заняться на выходных. Позже отпишусь тогда, буду держать в курсе! ><

Comment: Только уменя там была проверка флага в итерациях цикла до await, а не после )

Answer (score 0):

В общем да, цикл из синхронной функции никак не остановить, нужно делать асинхрон.
Пытался упростить код, чтобы решить более сложную задачу, но в итоге слишком упростил ))

В итоге получилось такое:

```
let reset = false;

async function main(){

    let ids = await get_ids();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 50) {

        let items = await get_items(ids.slice(i, i + 50));
        if (reset) break;
        
    }

    if(reset){
        reset = false;
        main();
    }
}

main();

let filter_clear = document.querySelector('.filter-clear');

filter_clear.addEventListener('click', function(){
    reset = true;
});
```